# Is it possible to send (thread_ts) like property in slackSend() fucntion Jenkins declarative Pipeline...?

Tags: jenkins, slack-api, slack-commands

I want to send a Jenkins response to Slack as a thread. Is it possible..?

slackSend(channel: "builds", message: "Started build", thread_ts: how?)

Answer (score 4):

```
node {
    def slackResponse = slackSend(channel: "cool-threads", message: "Here is the primary message")
    slackSend(channel: slackResponse.threadId, message: "Thread reply #1")
    slackSend(channel: slackResponse.threadId, message: "Thread reply #2")
}
```

reply broadcasted to the channel message

```
node {
    def slackResponse = slackSend(channel: "ci", message: "Started build")
    slackSend(channel: slackResponse.threadId, message: "Build still in progress")
    slackSend(
        channel: slackResponse.threadId,
        replyBroadcast: true,
        message: "Build failed. Broadcast to channel for better visibility."
    )
}
```

more info can be found in the official docs
https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin

Comment: A msg "Thread reply#1 & #2" will appear in slack as a norml msg rather than thread against a msg  "Here is a primary message"

Answer (score 2):

Per [this](https://edekler.nl/api-mngmt/enabling-threaded-slack-messages-while-using-the-jenkins-slack-plugin/) article, bot-user mode must be enabled. Adding `bot-user:true` to the slacksend command will accomplish this, but then I get a pipeline step